# Avro4S : Could not find implicit value for parameter builder

Tags: scala, avro4s

I am using avro4s

https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s

I wrote this code

```
implicit val schema = AvroSchema[SalesRecord]
val output = AvroOutputStream[SalesRecord](new File(outputLocation))
output.write(salesList)
output.flush
output.close
```

But I get a compile time error

```
could not find implicit value for parameter builder: shapeless.Lazy[....]
Not enough arguments for method apply
```

Comment: I sometimes get similar errors when I've forgotten () after object apply factory methods. perhaps your first line should read: AvroSchema[SalesRecord]( )   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in 1.2.x with private vals in a case class which caused the error you've seen here. That's fixed in 1.3.0 and should solve your problem.

(If it's not private vals, you'd need to post up your `SalesRecord` object for us to take a look at and I'll update this answer with a solution).